# How to tackle 'Invalid user credentials given' in Google Sites API?

Tags: google-api

We use google sites at my company, and I am trying to use google sites API to modify certain pages. The credentials that I use for signing in are: *username*@companyName.com and a unique password.One more thing to note, is that the url for our sites pages are in the following format: https://sites.google.com/a/*companyName*/NameOfYourPage

I just started using the Google Sites API, and was looking at one of the examples that they have given in their /samples/sites directory. (Got this after downloading the most recent zip file  https://code.google.com/p/gdata-python-client/downloads/list). Right now I was trying to run sites_examples.py.

So when I do run sites_examples.py and enter the site information as given above, I am asked to choose the authorization mechanism. I chose ClientLogin. When I enter the same user name and password (as I mentioned above) to access the sites page, it throws me: Invalid user credentials given.

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 0):

You can get this error if Google detects suspicious activity on your account.  To remedy

- log in to your Google account with the same credentials
- look for the warning from Google that notifies you of suspicious activity
- click on the link on the warning on Google's site
- follow Google's instructions to enable your client code